# Restlet not launching in Linux

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

When I launch Restlet J2SE on linux, I am getting the following exception. Any hint ?

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.addAllImpl(ILjava/util/Coll                                                                             ection;)V [line 1048]
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.addAll(Ljava/util/Collectio                                                                             n;)Z [line 627]
    at org.restlet.service.MetadataService.addCommonExtensions()V [line 371]
    at org.restlet.service.MetadataService.<init>()V [line 84]
    at org.restlet.Application.<init>(Lorg/restlet/Context;)V [line 172]
    at org.restlet.Application.<init>()V [line 140]
```

Comment: The environment is Power PC with Aionix VM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve by editing the restlet sources in ,
    org.restlet.service.MetadataService

```
 // Add all those mappings
    //Note : This is not working with in PowerPC with Aionix JVM
    //this.mappings.addAll(dm); 

    //Adding one by one works fine.
    for(MetadataExtension metadataExt : dm) {
        this.mappings.add(metadataExt);
    }
```